# What do I have to do to hide the title bar in Opera?

Tags: linux, opera, title-bar

What do I need to do the title bar in Opera on Linux? I am using Gnome 3 / GTK in this case.

Please note that I really mean the title bar, not the menu bar or tab bar.

Comment: go to this [link][1], may helps you.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7354/how-to-hide-the-titlebar-in-opera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the tab bar (yes, I know you want to change the *title* bar, bear with me) and de-select the option "Show Border". (Maximise the window to see the full effect.) Also see [this thread](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1441182) on the Opera forums.

Alternatively, depending on your flavour of Linux (not sure about GTK), your OS may allow you to achieve the same effect by using specific window decoration settings, or you could [use Compiz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7354/how-to-hide-the-titlebar-in-opera) to hide the window decorations altogether (the result may not be to everyone's taste).

Comment: Err, easier than I thought. Thanks, deselecting that option worked...

Comment: That option is not present in newer versions of Opera.

Comment: @cipricus: The Opera of 6 years ago was a completely different browser. In 2013, iirc, Opera switched from using Presto to using Blink (like Chrome).

Comment: Of course. I just thought a comment was needed.